# css layout issue with aligning some of my boxes

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to create a css template here using div tags.

What I'm trying to do is shown in this image:

[image]

however im having some issues. I can get box 1 to work well, and when i put box 2,3 and 4 in position they go where I want them.

However with box 5, it goes in the right position however it also forces box 4 to start from the same height as it. As shown in this image:

[image]

my code is:

I couldn't find a html live demo but copying and pasting this to one should work

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Leopold Planning </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untited Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
*
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
body
{
    background-image:url(background.png);
    background-color:#1f54bd;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    margin-top:0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:Lucinda Bright;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.contain
{
    width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.info
{
    width: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 300px;
}
.info1
{
    width: 990px;
    background-color: white;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px;

}
.contact
{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}


#navigation 
{
font-size:1.2em; 
width:180px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 10px;
float:left;
overflow: hidden;
}
#navigation ul
{
margin:0px; 
padding:0px;
}
#navigation li 
{
list-style: none;
} 

ul.top-level 
{
background:#ffffff
}
ul.top-level li {
 border-bottom: #C0C0C0 solid;
 border-width: 1px;
}

#navigation a {
 color: #D4A017;
 cursor: pointer;
 display:block;

 line-height: 25px;
 text-indent: 0px;
 text-decoration:none;
 width:100%;
}
#navigation a:hover{
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration:none;
}

#navigation li:hover {
 background: #2554C7;
 position: relative;
}

.contact_info
{
    width:180px;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.mainbody {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
}
.phone {
    width: 280px;
    background-color: white;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
}












</style>

</head>

<body>

<!-- banner removed  -->



<!-- container -->
<div class="contain">

<!-- WELCOME MESSAGE -->

    <div class="info1">
    <h2> Welcome to Leopold Planning</h2>
    <p>Thank you for visiting Leopold Planning, we hope you find what you are looking for and we are always willing to help!</p>
    </div>

<!-- NAVIGATION -->
    <div id="navigation">
                <ul class="top-level">

                <li><a id="displayText2" href="javascript:App();"><b>Planning Application</b></a></li>
                <li><a id="displayText3" href="javascript:cert();"><b>Certificate of Lawfulness Applications</b></a></li>
                <li><a id="displayText1" href="javascript:Appeal();"><b>Planning Appeals</b></a></li>
                        <li><a id="displayText" href="javascript:statement();"><b>Planning Statements</b></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><b>Site Appraisals/Stalled Sites</b></a></li>      

                        </ul>
    </div>

<!-- Main Body -->
    <div class="mainbody">

    <!-- top navigation -->
    <div id="navigation1">
        going to have three links here
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- main content -->
    <div class="mainbody">
    sadas



    </div>

<!-- Phone back -->
    <div class="phone">
    <h3>Phone Back</h3>
    <table align="center">
    <form action="" method="post">
    <tr><td align="left">Name:<font color="red">*</font></td><td> <input type="text" name="name_p" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="left">Number:<font color="red">*</font></td><td> <input type="text" name="number_p" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="p_submit" /></td></tr>
    </form>
    </table>
    </div>
<!-- Contact -->

<!-- Twitter -->







</div>




</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post a demo not a webpage.

Comment: Why not just make 4 box's, and separate box 3 into two rows

Comment: `<center>` was deprecated a loooong time ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML, put the code of the Phone back div before the Mainbody div

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick and thanks for everyone else for bearing with my code!

Answer (score 0):

Too much code. But maybe you have fixed the width of Box 3. Now the next code is for Box 5, which will come in the same line as Box 3 if it can fit, which it can't, so it moves to next line. Same goes for Box 4, which this time fits in the same line as Box 5. One solution can be defining Box 4 before Box 5. Other solution can be to put Box 3 and Box 4 in a common div with Box 3 floating left and width property set.

Answer (score 0):

```
       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Leopold Planning </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untited Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    *
    {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    body
    {
        background-image:url(background.png);
        background-color:#1f54bd;
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        margin-top:0px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family:Lucinda Bright;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .contain
    {
        width:1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;

    }
    .info
    {
        width: 500px;
        background-color: white;
        float: right;
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-right: 300px;
    }
    .info1
    {
        width: 990px;
        background-color: white;
        float: right;
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 5px;

    }
    .contact
    {
        width: 200px;
        background-color: white;
        float: right;
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 5px;
    }


    #navigation 
    {
    font-size:1.2em; 
    width:180px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    #navigation ul
    {
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;
    }
    #navigation li 
    {
    list-style: none;
    } 

    ul.top-level 
    {
    background:#ffffff
    }
    ul.top-level li {
     border-bottom: #C0C0C0 solid;
     border-width: 1px;
    }

    #navigation a {
     color: #D4A017;
     cursor: pointer;
     display:block;

     line-height: 25px;
     text-indent: 0px;
     text-decoration:none;
     width:100%;
    }
    #navigation a:hover{
     color: #fff;
     text-decoration:none;
    }

    #navigation li:hover {
     background: #2554C7;
     position: relative;
    }

    .contact_info
    {
        width:180px;
        background-color: white;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .mainbody {
        width: 500px;
        background-color: white;
        float:left;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .phone {
        position: relative;
        width: 280px;
        background-color: white;
        float: right;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 5px;
        clear: none;
    }












    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

    <!-- banner removed  -->



    <!-- container -->
    <div class="contain">

    <!-- WELCOME MESSAGE -->

        <div class="info1">
        <h2> Welcome to Leopold Planning</h2>
        <p>Thank you for visiting Leopold Planning, we hope you find what you are looking for and we are always willing to help!</p>
        </div>

    <!-- NAVIGATION -->
        <div id="navigation">
                    <ul class="top-level">

                    <li><a id="displayText2" href="javascript:App();"><b>Planning Application</b></a></li>
                    <li><a id="displayText3" href="javascript:cert();"><b>Certificate of Lawfulness Applications</b></a></li>
                    <li><a id="displayText1" href="javascript:Appeal();"><b>Planning Appeals</b></a></li>
                            <li><a id="displayText" href="javascript:statement();"><b>Planning Statements</b></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><b>Site Appraisals/Stalled Sites</b></a></li>      

          </ul>
        </div>

    <!-- Main Body -->
        <div class="mainbody">

        <!-- top navigation -->
        <div id="navigation1">
            going to have three links here
        </div>


        <!-- main content -->
        <div class="mainbody">
        sadas
        </div>
        </div>
     <div class="phone">
        <h3>Phone Back</h3>
        <table align="center">
        <form action="" method="post">
        <tr><td align="left">Name:<font color="red">*</font></td><td> <input type="text" name="name_p" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td align="left">Number:<font color="red">*</font></td><td> <input type="text" name="number_p" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="p_submit" /></td></tr>
        </form>
        </table>
     </div>


    <!-- Phone back -->

    <!-- Contact -->

    <!-- Twitter -->







    </div>




    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

this should work with you , you have misplaced some `</div>` , thats all